# How to increase Application cache (appcache) size limit in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

Our web application contain a few video(s),  It's offline by AppCache (HTML5), It need about 400MB content to be stored, How to increase AppCache size limit?

Comment: You need to provide more details as in what all you have tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I always got an error message from console "Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (2) http://localhost/media/transition.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

AppCache seems to be deprecated (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) is the most appropriate solution to store large files/blobs and it's supported in the most used web browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much, Great idea!